# Allow 'Fill-in' choices for multichoice not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, list-form, choice-field

I would like to add a column type "Choice" in a list and allow fill-in by users. It works for single choice column but not for multichoice column. The user can add a choice but this new value it's not add to list.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I can add multiple fill-in values to multiple selection choice column without any issue:

Make sure you click on **Add** after typing the fill-in value (do this for each fill-in value):

[image]

**Note**: Fill-in values will not be stored as options/choices in choice column settings automatically. This is by design in SharePoint.